# Освещён и освещен, есть ли разница? Освещен с "не" как пишется?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Освещён и освещен, есть ли смысловая или какая-то другая разница? 
Освещен с "не" как пишется? Встречала оба варианта.
1. Дом неосвещен.
2. Дом не освещен.
Как правильно?
Слово "освещен" вообще существует или нет?

Comment: А что такое "освещен"? Разве такое слово есть?

Comment: Это одно слово, только в одном Ё прописана, а в другом нет.

Comment: @Артём Луговой, по идее да, но раз спрашивают о смысловой разнице, то наверное, дело не только в написании ё.

Comment: А что вы имеете в виду: в доме темно, нет света или его не освятил священник?

Comment: Это одно слово, от корня ,,свет", употребляется по-разному, поэтому спрашиваю. Я смотрела в нац.корпусе, там все варианты есть,  неосвещен слитно тоже есть. Почему употребляется с "е" и с "ё", какая разница?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В любом случае ***не*** с кратким причастием пишется отдельно. Если краткое причастие мужского рода, то форма будет «освещён» (или «освящён», если от глагола «святить»), в кратких причастиях женского и среднего рода -е- («освещена, освещено»).